# Which programming languages can be used to develop in blackberry?

Tags: api, blackberry, programming-languages

I know that third party developers use the Blackberry API but what specific programming languages does it support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say Java is the best option since the BlackBerry platform is built on top of Java Micro Edition (Java ME).

Comment: It is not only the best option, it is the only option (unless you make a web-based app, that is), at least on Smartphones using BBOS version up to 7.x. The Blackberry API on those devices is Java-based. On the Playbook tablet, and smartphones starting with BBOS 10, Java is no longer being used. The OS on those devices is based on QNX instead, and the API uses C++.

Comment: How about the android emulator on the playbook. I dont know how easy it is in practice to convert an android app to run on playbook but according to RIM android on the playbook is possible.

Comment: The PlayBook OS, formally BlackBerry Tablet OS, is essentially the prototype for BlackBerry OS 10. The android emulator will be availalbe when Tablet OS 2.0 is released (scheduled for Feb 2012). But that won't be a solution for a hand held platform until BBOS 10 phones are released (not estimated for late 2012), and will never be an option for any of the current phones which will not run BBOS 10.

Answer (score 0):

- Cascades Qt/C++
- WebWorks HTML5
- Native SDK C/C++
- Adobe AIR ActionScript
- Android Runtime Java